# Foreach loop returns null after 10th iteration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, asp.net-core-2.0, google-books

I used the Google Books Api through .NET. and with MVC Core 2. I retrieve an IEnumerable of data and by a simple foreach loop iteration, I assign every book to a book object inside a list.
Here is the code which I customized from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/3301/google-books-search-with-c-sharp.aspx).

```
        public IEnumerable<Book> GetBooks(string query, int offset, int count)
    {

        var queryList = _booksService.Volumes.List(query);
        queryList.MaxResults = count;
        queryList.StartIndex = offset;
        var result = queryList.Execute();

        if (result != null) { 

        var books = result.Items.Select(b => new Book
        {
           // id = b.Id,
            title = b.VolumeInfo.Title,
            subtitle = b.VolumeInfo.Subtitle,
            authors = string.Join(",",b.VolumeInfo.Authors),
            publisher = b.VolumeInfo.Publisher,
            publishedDate = b.VolumeInfo.PublishedDate,
            description = b.VolumeInfo.Description,
            pageCount = (int)b.VolumeInfo.PageCount,
            category = string.Join(",",b.VolumeInfo.Categories),               
            maturityRating = b.VolumeInfo.MaturityRating,
            language = b.VolumeInfo.Language,
            smallThumbnail = b.VolumeInfo.ImageLinks.SmallThumbnail,
            thumbnail = b.VolumeInfo.ImageLinks.Thumbnail

        }).ToList();

        return books;

        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It was working fine before, but now, after the 10th iteration I get a "InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value." in my View,
in the following line:

```
var books = result.Items.Select(b => new Book
```

This is very weird, because the debugger shows that the request executed succesfully and I get results for this.

[image]

What could possible have gone wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post what you are passing for the parameters to the method, that way we can make sure we are looking at the exact same thing you are.

Comment: my main parameter is a string written like "subject=adventure", the offset is an int for the position inside the collection to start the list and the int count is the maximum results that I want fetched (the api allows 40)

Answer (score 1):

One of the properties values is `null`. Eg: The PageCount. When the debugger halts, check the current item has data for every property that you try to assign/use.

Also, the InnerException might contain the name of the property that is failing.